# Convert string to Jquery dataset

Tags: javascript

I want to covert this string to jquery data table. I can't do this.

```
var str = "96,xxx,212,xxxx||
100,yyy,123,yyyy";

My original DataSet structure like this 

var aDataSet = [['96','xxx','212','xxxx'],
        ['100','yyy','123','yyyy']];
```

This is my code what i tried;

```
var srchvalue = str.split('||');
 for (var e = 0; e < srchvalue.length; e++) {

                    alert(srchvalue[e]);
                    aDataSet.push(srchvalue[e]);
}
```

But it's not convert the actual format.

Comment: You mean "convert string to array"? This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to `split()` twice. You've done the first bit already. Then you will need to split the two strings in your array with the `,` as the separator.

You can use `aDataSet.push(srchvalue[e].split(','))` inside the `for` loop you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing in your array the result of a split on `"||"` which is a series of string like `"96,xxx,212,xxxx"`. You need to split that string too in order to have a matrix:

```
[...]    
aDataSet.push(srchvalue[e].split(','));
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I used the below code to convert it.

```
 var test = eval('[' + srchvalue[e].split(',') + ']');
 aDataSet.push(test);
```